Almost sure convergence of $\frac{\ln|\xi_n|}{n}$, where $\xi_n$ is a random point in a circle of radius $\xi_{n-1}$
Suppose $\xi_1$ is a random point in a circle of radius $1$ with uniform distribution and $\xi_{n}$ is a random point in a circle of radius $\xi_{n-1}$, $n \geq 2$. I need to show that
$$
\eta_n := \frac{\ln|\xi_n|}{n}
$$
converges a.s. as $n \to \infty$.
I managed to show that $\eta_n \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{d,\mathbb{P}} -\frac{1}{2}$. The density of $|\xi_1|$ is $p(x_1) = 2x_1\cdot I(0 \leq x_1 \leq 1)$ and the conditional density of $|\xi_n|$ given $|\xi_{n-1}| = x_{n-1} \in [0,1]$ is
$$
p(x_n \mid x_{n-1}) = \frac{2x_n}{x_{n-1}^2}I(0 \leq x_n \leq x_{n-1}).
$$
So $\varphi_{\eta_n}(t) = \mathbb{E}[|\xi|_1^{it}] = \int_0^1 2 x_1^{it+1}dx_1 = \frac{2}{it + 2}$ and using mathematical induction one can derive that
$$
\varphi_{\eta_{n}}(t) =  \frac{2n}{it + 2n} \cdot \mathbb{E}[|\xi_{n-1}|^{it/n}] = \frac{2n}{it + 2n} \cdot \varphi_{\eta_{n-1}}\left(\frac{n-1}{n}t\right) = \left( \frac{2n}{it + 2n}  \right)^n = \left( 1 + \frac{it/2}{n}  \right)^{-n} \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{} e^{-it/2}.
$$
But I was unable to prove the almost sure convergence. I thought of proving
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}\left[\left| \eta_n + \frac{1}{2} \right| > \varepsilon \right] < \infty
$$
so I tried to compute
$$
\mathbb{P}\left[\left| \eta_n + \frac{1}{2} \right| > \varepsilon \right]
$$
but didn't end up with something nice.
Thank you in advance.

Conditioned on $\xi_{n-1}=a>0$, the distribution of $\xi_{n}$ is given by
$$
\mathbb{P}(\xi_n\le x\mid \xi_{n-1}=a)=\frac{\pi x^2}{\pi a^2}=\left(\frac x a\right)^2,\quad 0\le x\le a
$$
hence if you define $\eta_n=\frac{\xi_n}{\xi_{n-1}}$, then $\mathbb{P}(\eta_n\le x)=x^2$, $0\le x\le 1$.
A key observation is that random variables $\eta_n$ are i.i.d. Hence
$$
\xi_n=\xi_0 \eta_1\eta_2\dots\eta_n \quad\Longrightarrow\quad
\frac{\ln \xi_n}n=\frac1n\ln\xi_0 +\frac{\ln\eta_1+\ln\eta_2+...+\ln\eta_n}n.
$$
By the strong law of large numbers,
$$
\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n \ln\eta_i\to \mathbb{E}\ln\eta=\int_0^1 \ln(x)\frac{d}{dx} \mathbb{P}(\eta_n\le x)dx=-\frac12   \quad a.s.
$$
and $\frac1n\ln\xi_0\to 0$, yielding the result.
